# Getting UIImage of MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a whole bunch of MKMapView I'd like to get UIImage of (one per UItableViewCell I have). Pretty easy, I use ;

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_map.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
[_map.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *mapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

_mapImageView.image = mapImage;
```

in my UITableViewCell subclass.

Problem is : `MKMapView` wont draw its tiles if the `UITableViewCell` is not onscreen, so when I scroll my `UITableView`, I have a bunch of `UIImageView` with a grey grid in there. Anybody has a solution for that ? How would I force the `MKMapView` to be rendered in the graphic context ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly... You want to present a UITableView with an image of Maps in each of the cell ? To do so you plan to have create an image for each of the cells ? I assume your MKMapView is actually not showing ?

Comment: You do understand correctly. My `MKMapView` is showing the time it loads its content, and then afterward is swapped with a `UIImageView` for performance and other  glitches that can appear when a `UITableViewCell` is presenting a `MKMapView` (such as content reload when the cell is highlighted)

Comment: Hum... Indeed the map will need some time to render, actually just downloading the correct map to display will take time and eventually, if the user scroll i think you won't be able to load the map in time. Forcing MKMapView to render won't help, i fear the whole system takes too much time. Isn't it possible to show a dummy image and actually load the map when user tap on a cell ?

Comment: That is not the case here, I draw the image when I receive word from the `MKMapView` when it is fully loaded  (check `MKMapViewDelegate`). So I am sure the `mapView` is loaded. Whenever the `delegate` method is not called (which happen some times, because rendering tiles is not considered 'loading' by the `mapView`, then the mapView stays in the cell, which is fine provided that it is a minority.

Comment: Do you have multiple instance of the MKMapView (one for each cells) or only one for all the cells ?

Comment: My point was, each MKMapView will need time to load the data to present. Before it finish loading this data, the user might have scroll which will hide your MKMapView. This means 1) Your MKMapView might stop its loading 2) You will need to ask it to load other content for the next cells. So as long as the user scrolls, it will be hard (if not impossible) to render the images, which would explain the gray grid images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) will probably get me out of trouble (Google Static Maps API V2)

**-Edit-**
Actually implemented that: way less hackish than what I wanted to do, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

When I needed to render an entire tableview at the same time, I resized the tableview so that it was big enough to display all of the cells it had.

Change the frame of your table so that its height is numberOfCells*heightOfCell, render, and change the frame back.

Comment: Unfortunately that would not be a solution since I have multiple `UITableView` that contain such cells, somes cells are actually loaded while their tableView is not onscreen

Comment: Maybe create an array of map views, and iterate through them. Put each on screen in turn, render it, and then hide it. It's possible to do this without the process being seen by the user.

Comment: I think I will need to try this. How would you make it so that the user would not notice ?

Comment: Put the view that you're putting your map views into underneath another view, or render them offscreen (I'm not sure if the second one works for map views). It also possible to do the entire thing before `layoutSubviews` is called, in which case the views will never show up onscreen (this is how the frame change works).